# Como agregar una barra de progreso

Tags: c#, asp.net, progressbar

Tengo una aplicacion web que tiene un boton de descarga. Este boton tiene como objetivo descargar un archivo csv.

La aplicacion funciona bien pero no tengo nada que pueda mostrarle al usuario que el proceso se esta descargando (como una barra de progreso).

He intentado incorporar varias formas pero nada me resulta.

Cual seria la mejor forma de proceder?

Este es mi foton en la pagina .aspx:

```
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress"
AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"
runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>           
    <center></center><img alt="progress" src="img/loader.gif"/>
       Processing...           
     </center>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>


        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

           <center><asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Download" OnTextChanged="Download" Height="60" 
                  Width="160" Font-Size="16" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#C6D5E2" BorderStyle="Groove" OnClick="Download"/></center>
                <br />
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Mi problema es el siguiente al tratar de incorporar la solucion que menciono.

La barra de progreso aparece bien, pero desaparece varios segundos antes de que termine el proceso.

Al usar estar solucion, el archivo no se descarga y el proceso se para.

Comment: Hola a arancibia. Aunque no funcione, podrías mostrar el código que has intentado? Igualmente lo ideal seria hacer un onclientclick a javascript y des de ahí mostrar una carga

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario. He ido a modificar mi pregunta para hacerla mas clara. Saludos